# What's the Idiomatic Way in Kotlin to Use Streams with map and orElseThrow?

Tags: kotlin, java-stream, option-type

I am transitioning from Java to Kotlin and am used to working with Java Streams. I have the following two Kotlin snippets that essentially do the same thing: they attempt to create a retrospective through a client call and map it to a model. If the creation or mapping fails, an exception should be thrown.

Solution 1:

```
val createdRetro = 
retroClient.createRetro(newRetroDto)?.let(retroMapper::toModel)
    ?: throw Exception("Could not create retro")
```

Solution 2:

```
val createdRetro2 = 
sequenceOf(retroClient.createRetro(newRetroDto))
    .filterNotNull()
    .map { retroMapper.toModel(it) }
    .firstOrNull() ?: throw Exception("Could not create retro")
```

The second approach seems more familiar to me coming from Java, where I often used Streams with map and orElseThrow.

Which of these is more idiomatic in Kotlin? Is there a more Kotlin-native approach that combines the readability and safety features I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would certainly not create a sequence for this, so option 2 is out of the question IMO, unless you do want to process multiple elements.

The first option is ok, but it would be even better without `let` (for my personal taste), and this is probably due to the fact that the conventions are not respected here. `X.toY()` should convert an X to a Y. It's strange to have `X.toY(Z)` that converts Z to Y. So I would rather redefine the signature of `toModel` so the receiver is the thing that is converted. That actually plays much nicer in chains:

```kotlin
val createdRetro = retroClient.createRetro(newRetroDto)?.toModel(retroMapper)
    ?: throw Exception("Could not create retro")
```

You could even remove `retroMapper` here by defining the extension `toModel` in a scope that has access to the mapper.

Note that you could also simply fail early without changing anything else:

```kotlin
val rawCreatedRetro = retroClient.createRetro(newRetroDto)
    ?: throw Exception("Could not create retro")
val createdRetro = retroMapper.toModel(rawCreatedRetro)
```

IMO the signature that you chose for `toModel` encourages this kind of style instead.